# How to get all values from indexeddb

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb

I am working on storing some data in the indexedDb.

I have created a method which saves the data into the indexedDb. I have stored exactly 49 records. I am trying to retrieve **all of them**. I have written the below code for getting the values. No other code except this line exist in my js file.

```
function crap() {
var indexedDb = window.indexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB;

var IDBKeyRange = window.IDBKeyRange || window.webkitIDBKeyRange;

var openedDb = indexedDb && indexedDb.open;

var isIndexDbTransactionPossible = window.IDBTransaction || window.webkitIDBTransaction;
if (isIndexDbTransactionPossible) {
    isIndexDbTransactionPossible.READ_WRITE = isIndexDbTransactionPossible.READ_WRITE || 'readwrite';
    isIndexDbTransactionPossible.READ_ONLY = isIndexDbTransactionPossible.READ_ONLY || 'readonly';
}

var request = indexedDb.open('Offline', DB_VERSION);

request.onupgradeneeded = function(e) {
    var db = e.target.result;

    if (db.objectStoreNames.contains('tab')) {
        db.deleteObjectStore('tab');
    }

    var store = db.createObjectStore('tab', {keyPath: 'id', autoIncrement: true});
};

request.onsuccess = function(e) {
    console.log("DB opened");
    var db = e.target.result;

    var store= db.transaction('tab', IDBTransaction.READ_ONLY).objectStore('tab');

    var cursor = store.openCursor();

    cursor.onsuccess = function(event) {

        var c = event.target.result;

        if (c) {
            console.log("New value")
            c.continue();
        }
    };
};
}
```

I am seeing "New Value" printed 124 times. I am not sure why the cursor.continue() is not returning null after 49th attempt. Any help is much appreciated.

I am positive that this method is not called more than one time. "DB opened" is logged only one.

Comment: What does db.transaction('tab').objectStore('tab').count().onsuccess = function(e) { console.log(e.target.result); } show?

Comment: (And it's probably just debugging code, but checking readyState inside an onsuccess handler is pointless. The "success" event will only be fired at a request when the request's readyState is "done".)

Comment: @JoshuaBell: Yes. This is just for debugging. It adds no value to the code.

Comment: Your code looks fine. So it's time to question your assumptions. Verify the number of records in the store. Log cursor.key each iteration as well and see what the unexpected records are.

Comment: Also, ensure that you don't have other code interfering. If you had later code - not shown - that overwrote cursor you could be seeing the results of iterating a different store.

Comment: One more thought: Safari's implementation of IDB is buggy - stores are not isolated. So check in Chrome or Firefox.

Answer (score 11):

Just use the getAll function:

```
    var allRecords = store.getAll();
    allRecords.onsuccess = function() {
        console.log(allRecords.result);
    };
```

Read more in the documentation: [Working with IndexedDB](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/working-with-indexeddb)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of checking readyState, just check for whether the cursor is defined in your cursor request callback. Here is an example. I modified the names of your variables slightly for clarity.

```
cursorRequest.onsuccess = function(event) {
  var cursor = event.target.result;

  if(cursor) {
    var value = cursor.value;
    console.log('New value:', value);
    cursor.continue();
  } else {
    // Undefined cursor. This means either no objects found, 
    // or no next object found
    // Do not call cursor.continue(); in this else branch because 
    // there are no more objects over which to iterate.  
    // Coincidentally, this also means we are done iterating.
    console.log('Finished iterating');
  }
}
```

Comment: The check is adding no value to my code. The next lines are doing exactly the same as your answer.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand the meaning of your response here. Could you please clarify?

Comment: Updated the question... Can you please have a look?